# Is there a LIKE operator that will include NULL values?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008, with a C# front end.  I'm trying to pass a SQL string from C# to SQL Server, and there are 2 fields in my WHERE statement that sometimes might contain NULL values.  I've got this code on my Page Load in the code-behind (this is for a report that will be placed in a datagrid):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlconnectionStatus = new SqlConnection(str);
        string DDL_Value = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["DDL_Val"]);
        string Val_Value = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Val_Val"]);
        string Trk_Value = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Trk_Val"]);
        string StDt_Value = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["StDt_Val"]);
        string EnDt_Value = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["EnDt_Val"]);

        string BTN_Value;
        // Because the date is stored as an INT, you have to request the string and then
        //   convert it to an INT
        string StDT_Vals = Request.QueryString["StDt_Val"].ToString();
        string EnDT_Vals = Request.QueryString["EnDt_Val"].ToString(); 
        string sqlquery;

            sqlquery = "Select DISTINCT PL.PROC_NM as Agent_Name, CCM.UNIQUE_CLAIM_ID as Unique_ID, CCM.CLAIM_ID as Claim_Number, ";
            sqlquery = sqlquery + "CCM.SOCSEC as Employee_Last_Digit, CCM.DATE_IMPORTED as Import_Date, CCM.Orig_Open_Date as Original_Review_Date, ";
            sqlquery = sqlquery + "AGL.ACCT_GRP as Account_Name, AL.ACCT_NUM as Account_Number, CCM.CDBBEN as Benefit_Option, CCM.BENEFIT_TYPE1 as Benefit_Type1, ";
            sqlquery = sqlquery + "CCM.BENEFIT_TYPE2 as Benefit_Type2, CCM.BENEFIT_TYPE3 as Benefit_Type3, CCM.Cmplt as Review_Validated, CCM.Vldtn_Cmmnts as Validation_Comments, ";
            sqlquery = sqlquery + "CCM.Gtkpr_Cmmnts as Gatekeeper_Comments, TS.StatusText as Tracking_Status ";
            sqlquery = sqlquery + "from ClosedClaims_MERGE CCM ";
            sqlquery = sqlquery + "LEFT JOIN PROC_LIST PL ON CCM.Spare = PL.LOGIN ";
            sqlquery = sqlquery + "LEFT JOIN ACCT_LIST AL ON AL.ACCT_NUM = CCM.CDBACC ";
            sqlquery = sqlquery + "LEFT JOIN ACCT_GRP_LIST AGL ON AGL.ACCT_GRP_PK = AL.ACCT_GRP_FK ";
            sqlquery = sqlquery + "LEFT JOIN TrackingStatus TS ON TS.StatusCode = CCM.TrackingStatus ";
            sqlquery = sqlquery + "WHERE CCM.Spare LIKE '" + DDL_Value + "' AND CCM.Cmplt LIKE '" + Val_Value + "' AND CCM.TrackingStatus IN (" + Trk_Value + ") AND CCM.DATE_IMPORTED >= '" + StDt_Value + "' AND CCM.DATE_IMPORTED <= '" + EnDt_Value + "'";
    }
```

The code is sound, it works perfectly fine if a value is selected for all report parameters.  The problem is CCM.Spare and CCM.Cmplt can have specific values chosen from a dropdown, or they can be left blank.  If left blank, then they need to pull ALL values, whether they're NULL or not.  When I leave one (or both) blank, that's where the SQL fails.

I tried checking for blanks and setting the variable equal to '%', but that obviously isn't working; it will only pick up records where there is a value in the field.

I want to do this with one statement if possible before I go cludging it with some If/Then/Else loops.

Is this possible?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Especially when it comes straight from user input (`Request.QueryString`). This is just asking to be hacked.

Comment: And no postback check or use of StringBuilder.  This code is flat out hard to read.

Comment: IMO, the code is not sound. Aside from the SQL Injection issues, `Request.QueryString` always returns a string. Thus, there is no need to use `Convert.ToString` on the results. Worse, (and aside from the inconsistency) the use of `ToString` directly on an item from `QueryString` might throw a null object exception if `Request.QueryString` returns a null instance for the given key.

Comment: I do appreciate the comments, but for my use I really just needed the answer that Arturo provided.  I was asking for an answer, not a critique of my coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, I just included the code for the first criteria.
As recommended above, don't concatenate your parameters; the second option is the best way to do it:

```
sqlquery = sqlquery + 
    "WHERE CCM.Spare " + (DDL_Value == null ? "IS NULL" : "LIKE '" + DDL_Value + "'") + " AND ...";
```

```
sqlquery = sqlquery + 
    "WHERE CCM.Spare " + (DDL_Value == null ? "IS NULL" : "LIKE @par1") + " AND ...";
```

Additionaly to increase the speed of your query you could do:

```
sqlquery = sqlquery + 
    "WHERE " + (DDL_Value != null ? "CCM.Spare LIKE @par1 AND " : "") + "...";
```

this will ignore the whole criteria on `CCM.Spare` if your parameter is null.

Comment: This won't return non-null values for CCM.Spare

Answer (score 1):

If you want all possible values of CCM.Spare and CCM.Cmplt, you simply need to leave off the predicate. Build a separate query (preferable using parametrized queries, as marc_s points out) that omits the `WHERE` clause referencing the empty dropdown value.